# How to pass AT commands to Lora from ESP32 UART?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-nano, esp32, iot, lora

I have connected "Reyax RYLR998" Lora module to ESP32 UART2, but AT commands passed through Hardware serial not working.

```cpp
#define RXD2 16
#define TXD2 17

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial2.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);

    Serial.print("\nSetting Lora Module \n");

    Serial2.print("AT+BAND=865000000\r\n");
    if (Serial2.available())
        Serial.println(Serial2.read());
    delay(1000);

    Serial2.print("AT+ADDRESS=1\r\n");
    if (Serial2.available())
        Serial.println(Serial2.read());
    delay(1000);

    Serial2.print((String)"AT+NETWORKID=5\r\n");
    if (Serial2.available())
        Serial.println(Serial2.read());
    delay(1000);
}

void loop()
{
    while (Serial2.available())
    {
        Serial.print(char(Serial2.read()));
    }
}
```

I tried

```cpp
Serial2.print((String)"AT+NETWORKID=5\n");
Serial2.println((String)"AT+NETWORKID=5\r");
Serial2.print((String)"AT+NETWORKID=5\r");
```

Nothing worked, no response from AT command,
Please help me I have been working on same problem for 2days.

[image: Connection of RYLR998 with EPS32]

[![Here all AT commands works well][2]][2]

Comment: Add a wiring diagram to your question and a link to the documentation for your Lora module. You appear to have set the baud rate of the Lora module's UART to 9600 but Serial2 of the ESP32 is still at 115200. These have to match. The 9600 is stored in the Lora flash for subsequent connections.

Comment: It is a good idea to try using an FTDI device to connect between the LORA module and the PC so you can issue commands through the serial console to LORA as your second picture shows. However,  you appear to connected TX and RX incorrectly. These must be crossed over. TX on one device to RX on the other etc. Experiment with the baud rate on the serial console say 9600 or 115200.

Comment: Sorry, i connected it correct, wrong in image, i taken it from other place, i connected tx to rx and rx to tx

Comment: The documentation is here: https://reyax.com/products/RYLR998 . Try using the FTDI device connected to the Lora module with the USB cable connected to your PC. Ignore the ESP32 for the moment. Simply issue the command "AT" then <enter> on the serial console and it should give a response "+OK". Start with a baud rate of 115200 on the serial console. If that fails, try down to 9600. The FTDI may not be able to supply enough power for the transmit function but should be enough for the "AT" test.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly when connected to USB and give AT command. How long to wait and how to wait after i give AT command to lora module through ESP32 SoftwareSerial?

Comment: I would try issuing the AT command, waiting 1 second for the result to be available then do the following `while (Serial2.available())
 Serial.print(Serial2.read());` . Try with just the simple "AT" to start with. What baud rate did you use in the serial monitor for your successful tests with the FTDI adapter ?

Comment: Please either correct or delete the image in your question with the incorrect FTDI wiring of TX/RX. If you get a successful connection between the LORA and the ESP32 modules, please add an answer to your question with the code that you used. It may help someone else.

Comment: I literally gave-up, code is working with Node MCU, i think ESP32 need some setup etc. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to Lora module and ESP32 and only playing around for a week.

I have successfully sent AT commands to RYLR998 module via ESP32 and received messages via other RYLR998 connected to another computer via USB UART serial.  You need use `trim()` before you send your string to `Serial2`.(ryltr998)

```
trim()
[StringObject Function]
Description
Get a version of the String with any leading and trailing whitespace removed. The trim() function modifies the String in place rather than returning a new one.

Syntax
myString.trim()
```